# C# DataView Sort Filter

Tags: c#, dataview

I am trying to sort a DataView by 'PartNum ASC, OrderNum ASC'.

I then apply a calculation to one of the columns on my dataview called 'Difference' which is the difference between 2 columns on each row, 'Reserved - PickingDemand'.

Once the 'Difference' has been calculated, I then need to sort the DataView by the 'Difference' column.

The code I have is as follows (simplified):

```
gridDataView.dataView.Sort = "FulfillmentPicking.PartNum ASC, FulfillmentPicking.OrderNum ASC";

for (int i = 0; i < gridDataView.dataView.Count; i++){
gridDataView.dataView[i]["FulfillmentPicking.Difference"] = Convert.ToInt32(gridDataView.dataView[i]["FulfillmentPicking.Reserved"]) - Convert.ToInt32(gridDataView.dataView[i]["FulfillmentPicking.PickingDemand"]);
}

gridDataView.dataView.Sort = "FulfillmentPicking.Difference ASC";
```

The second 'Sort' is causing an exception to be thrown. The exception simply states the program has stopped responding and then the program restarts.

Is it possible to use 2 sorts on a DataView?

Comment: What kind of object is gridDataView?

Comment: It is a 'DataView' object

Comment: You need to find out which exception is being thrown.

Comment: I understand that knowing what exception is being thrown would be significantly useful in debugging this problem. Putting exceptions aside, I am working on theory. Is it possible to use 2 separate sorting methods on a DataView? I assume the use of 2 sorts is causing the exception and the program to crash.

Comment: It is possible, in simplest case it works fine.             `var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Dif", typeof(int));
            table.Rows.Add(1, 0, 0);
            var dataView = new DataView(table);
            dataView.Sort = "A ASC, B ASC";
            for (int i = 0; i < dataView.Count; i++){
                dataView[i]["Dif"] = Convert.ToInt32(dataView[i]["A"]) - Convert.ToInt32(dataView[i]["B"]);
            }
            dataView.Sort = "Dif ASC";`